# Java―good size for a char buffer

Tags: java, io, buffer

I am coding a little java based tool to process mysqldump files, which can become quite large (up to a gigabyte for now). I am using this code to read and process the file:

```
BufferedReader reader = getReader();
BufferedWriter writer = getWriter();

char[] charBuffer = new char[CHAR_BUFFER_SIZE];
int readCharCout;
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

while( ( readCharCout = reader.read( charBuffer ) ) > 0 )
{
    buffer.append( charBuffer, 0, readCharCout );
    //processing goes here
}
```

What is a good size for the `charBuffer`? At the moment it is set to 1000, but my code will run with an arbitrary size, so what is best practice or can this size be calculated depending on the file size?

Thanks in ahead,
greetings philipp

Comment: Oracle's `BufferedReader` already uses a default buffer of `8192`.

Comment: I don't know if there's a standard for this as it'll depend on your available memory.  I would recommend experimenting with it at different sizes to see how it affects your performance

Comment: Or perhaps @SotiriosDelimanolis knows more about it than I do... lol

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis how would you know default size of BufferedReader ? can you share link?

Comment: @StormeHawke AFAIK the best values are 4096 and 8192, which value to use depends entirely on your hard drive speed.

Comment: For what it's worth, `StringBuffer` is a fairly heavyweight object. It's thread-safe and everything; it doesn't seem like the best option for... much of anything. It shouldn't be confused with an NIO buffer.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis but then you get the wrong idea. Nor OpenJDK nor HotSpot source code are **the codes**. If the size is not specified in the javadoc, then you **must not** assume it will always be 8192, note that JRockit or IBM JVM can change this.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't get like size but initial capacity of 16 characters.

Comment: @NFE Please rephrase that, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis sorry, From where you said initially default buffer of 8192. I just want to know, I goggled but didn't get any link.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer, use StringBuilder instead. http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2013/04/why-synchronized-stringbuffer-was-never.html

Comment: @NFE Just like Luiggi Mendoza stated, it depends on the implementation. I was referring to Oracle JDK 7's implementation. The [OpenJDK also seems to use that size](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/BufferedReader.java).

Comment: I tried 4096 and 8192 what seems to be faster… What happens if the value becomes too high?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am checking in jdk6. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should always be a power of 2.  The optimal value is based on the OS and disk format.  In code I've seen 4096 is often used, but the bigger the better.

Also, there are [better ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file#326440) to load a file into memory.

Comment: More than a power of 2, it should be a power of 1024.

Comment: I tries a bunch of values which were a power of 2, all ran fine. But except for very small values I could not see any extraordinary performance gains, but I guess that is due to my implementation

Comment: I could be due to a lot of factors.  Many OSes and disk controllers are smart enough to read blocks ahead of time.  When that occurs, your buffer size doesn't matter much, except for the cost of round-tripping to the OS API.